Edit formulas using VBA
For personal accounting, I have a relatively complex formula to edit for each two week period.
=SUMIFS(Table3[Amount],Table3[Category],E6,Table3[Date Entered],">"&Sheet3!B3,Table3[Date Entered],"<"&Sheet3B4)

I need to change the Sheet3 references down by 1.
I tried using record macro to get a feel for the things I need to adjust, but doing it variably is too far for me.

You shouldn't use VBA. A lot of people think that VBA is the holy grail for us mortals. But you can do much more with regular formulas then you think.
The solution is to get a date that only changes every 14 days.
Just get the modulus of 14 of today(), subtract it from today() and you end up with a date that increases only every 14th day by 14.
In a formula:
=TODAY() - MOD(TODAY(),14)

You can add an offset of max 13 to shift the date when it has to increase:
=TODAY() - MOD(TODAY(),14) + OFFSET


Doesn't Today() change? i wanted to the data to stick around to look at (It's personal finance, so it's not going to be crazy large). I did not know though that I could do that woah. I think that'll be really useful for creating reminders. If I didn't want to record that to determine how often I'm overbudget.

Yes, today() does change every day. It is difficult to tell what best works in your case. Maybe you could show a screenshot in your question of the table(s) you have and what result you need? Maybe it is better not to use different sheets, since it is a little bit more difficult to change sheets (Sheet3, Sheet4, etc.) then cells.

Yea Sure! let me post the Images , I know that i 1000% did the wrong formatting for that long table that I wanted to know how to write the VBA for in the first place but i didn't think about that till after i figured out the solution.
